# Utilizar FormatNumber o FormatCurrency para mis calculos en Vb.Net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, .net, vb6

Hola amigos tengo una función que devuelve un `string` obtenido de la suma de varios valores.

```
Private Function Suma() As String
        Dim remu, sac, vac, ext, asig As Decimal
        Dim total As Decimal


        remu = FormatNumber(TextBox1.Text, 2)

        ext = FormatNumber(TextBox2.Text, 2)

        asig = FormatNumber(TextBox3.Text, 2)

        vac = FormatNumber(TextBox4.Text, 2)

        sac = FormatNumber(TextBox5.Text, 2)


        total = remu + ext + asig + vac + sac

        Return FormatNumber(total, 2,,, TriState.False)

    End Function
```

Mi primera consulta en esta comunidad es puntualmente si utilizar `FormatNumber` o `FormatCurrency` y si en la conversión de valores desde los `textBox` a las variables hacerlo `Decimal` o `Double`.

Esta es una función **FUNDAMENTAL** en mi soft y no puede fallar por eso quiero estar completamente seguro que funcionará correctamente en todas la Computadoras independientemente como este configurado el panel de control (*sep decimal punto o coma*) ya que también se guardan en una Base de Datos Mysql y he tenido problema con las comas al pasar valores.

> **ACLARACION:** siempre se utilizarán 2 decimales y valores positivos y se restringe el uso de la coma a los `TextBox` para evitar inconvenientes en el formato.
>   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
>   introducir la descripción del enlace aquí

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te quieres asegurar de que trabajas con datos decimales para poder operar la suma, yo haría lo siguiente:

```
Private Function Suma() As String

    Dim remu, sac, vac, ext, asig As Decimal
    Dim total As Decimal
    Dim decimalParsed As Decimal

    If Decimal.TryParse(TextBox1.Text.Replace(".", ","), decimalParsed) Then
        remu = Decimal.Parse(TextBox1.Text.Replace(".", ","))
    Else
        remu = 0
    End If

    If Decimal.TryParse(TextBox2.Text.Replace(".", ","), decimalParsed) Then
        ext = Decimal.Parse(TextBox2.Text.Replace(".", ","))
    Else
        ext = 0
    End If

    If Decimal.TryParse(TextBox3.Text.Replace(".", ","), decimalParsed) Then
        asig = Decimal.Parse(TextBox3.Text.Replace(".", ","))
    Else
        asig = 0
    End If

    If Decimal.TryParse(TextBox4.Text.Replace(".", ","), decimalParsed) Then
        vac = Decimal.Parse(TextBox4.Text.Replace(".", ","))
    Else
        vac = 0
    End If

    If Decimal.TryParse(TextBox5.Text.Replace(".", ","), decimalParsed) Then
        sac = Decimal.Parse(TextBox5.Text.Replace(".", ","))
    Else
        sac = 0
    End If

    total = remu + ext + asig + vac + sac

    Return FormatNumber(total, 2,,, TriState.False)

End Function
```

Con **TryParse**, asegurarme que recibo un valor decimal, y con **Replace**, pasar el punto por coma para que adquiera un valor decimal. Luego, con **Decimal.Parse** convertirlo a un objeto de tipo decimal, para poder operar la suma con criterio.

En caso de que **TryParse** fuera resultado False, se podría devolver un error, o sumar **CERO**. Eso como te hayan precisado las reglas de negocio.

**EDITO:** corrijo orden de punto y de la coma en Replace tras verificarlo con el usuario que ha realizado la pregunta.

Comment: hola amigo muchas gracias por tu respuesta, mira copie tal como dices la funcion y la reproduzco en una imagen y fijate q el resultado es indeseado ya que no refleja  113.20 como espero sino lo que muestra la captura que pondre abajo en la descripcion(ya que aca no veo la forma de hacerlo)

Comment: Por lo que veo en tu pantallazo, se está "fumando" el punto separador del decimal "10.2" y lo suma como "102". Haz una prueba: "ext = Decimal.Parse(TextBox2.Text.Replace(",", "."))" sustitúyelo por "ext = Decimal.Parse(TextBox2.Text)", y me comentas para editar la respuesta.

Comment: Si, por lo que veo, obligas a la aplicación a ingresar un punto, no necesitas realmente hacer el replace. Si lo que te he dicho antes de prueba no te vale, prueba esto otro: ext = Decimal.Parse(TextBox2.Text.Replace(".", ",")). Es bastante probable que yo mismo me haya liado con los separadores decimales en VB .NET y en BBDD. Es un tema bastante lioso; ya no te cuento en JQuery y jugando con separadores de miles...

Comment: LO que sí es correcto es que uses Decimal.TryParse y Decimal.Parse para asegurarte que trabajas con datos decimales.

Comment: Lo pruebo a la tarde y comento!!.

Comment: Gracias amigo anduvo perfecto y me sirvio de mucho tu aclaracion!!

Comment: Me alegro que te haya funcionado :) He editado ya la respuesta, por si a algún otro usuario le pudiera ayudar.